# Docker: Why Do Variables Passed From .env Linger in the Container Even After They Are Removed From .env and Rebuilt

Tags: javascript, docker, azure-iot-edge

I'm trying to understand why env variables inside my Docker container keep appearing when I've clearly removed or commented them out from my `.env` file. I'm fairly new to Docker and don't know if this is expected behavior or an anomaly.

The way my system is setup, I spin up an instance of Azure's IoT Edge server locally (via `deployment.template.json`) which builds the Docker container and populates the environmental variables using the associated `.env` file.

Now what's perplexing me is that if I were to completely stop the server (not pause), comment out/remove the variable from the `.env` file, restart the server, and inspect the container (`docker container inspect`), I still see the variable name and value. I've also used `docker system prune -a --volumes` after stopping the server to prune my system and volumes, then restarted the server only to see the variable still listed.

Just in case it helps, inside my `deployment.template.json` I'm passing my variables as `MY_VAR=${MY_VAR}`. Then in my `.env` file I have the variable as `MY_VAR=abc123`.

From my `Dockerfile`:

```
# -------------
# Build Sources
# -------------
FROM node:10-alpine as builder

# Install additional git and openssh dependencies and make sure GitLab domain is accepted by SSH
RUN apk add --no-cache openssh git curl \
  && mkdir /root/.ssh/ \
  && touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts \
  && ssh-keyscan gitlab.com github.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts

WORKDIR /app

# Install app dependencies
RUN npm i -g typescript --no-cache --silent
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci --only=production --silent

# Copy sources and build
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# ----------------
# Production Image
# ----------------
FROM node:10-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache curl

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules /app/node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/dist /app/dist
COPY . .

USER node
CMD ["node", "dist/index.js"]
```

Comment: did you tried `docker build --no-cache -t your_image .`? it might the case these are still picked from the cache

Comment: I have not. Is the period at the end part of it? So for argument sake, it will be something as such `docker build --no-cache -t a12bc345 .`

Comment: `.` it mean that the dockerfile is the same path where you running the `docker build` command.

Comment: Before I run that command, let me show you the `Dockerfile` associated with this Azure module (see original post above). Don't worry about `Production Image` as I'm running this in a dev environment. Can I essentially put the `--no-cache` part in here somewhere? Of course I do see it being included a couple times already.

Comment: are you using `docker compose` to build image? `--no-cache` in dockerfile is for docker instruction not for `docker build`. you need to run `docker-compose build --no-cache` or `docker build --no-cache`

Comment: As if things weren't complex already, the Docker images get created during the CI/CD process in GitLab. I wonder if I can just run `docker-compose build --no-cache` or `docker build --no-cache` outside of this process.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199343/discussion-between-adiii-and-mix-master-mike).

Comment: Unless you stopped the container and then removed it then you're still going to be using the same container after a system reboot or `docker system prune`. `docker stop <container>` then `docker container prune` then `docker run --rm ..` to run a new container instance from your build.

Comment: to your comment about `docker container prune`, I do run that plus `docker image prune` (after `docker system prune -a --volumes`) but both always say 0B have been removed. but the one thing I don't necessarily do is stop docker. Let me give that a try.

Comment: Okay, so I did run stop my docker container, pruned everything, restarted the server and it was still there. I then repeated myself but before restarting the server I restarted my computer. And guess what? The value was no longer there. Yay! So this confirms your caching suspicion. I'm going to search to see what ways there are to purge my cache. I'll post what method eventually works.

Answer (score 0):

you can run "docker inspect" to your container and see what environment variables are defined in docker create options.

you can also check docker create options in Azure Portal.

Comment: True. And that's what I've been doing. Specifically `docker container inspect <container>`.